# How do i control word wrapping in a TextArea?

Tags: javafx-2, java-7

When I set wrapText property to true on a TextArea, it auto-wraps when it encounters space, period and semicolon (as far as I can tell) before a word that will be too long for the width of the TextArea.  How can I control the actual wrapping rule?  Can I change it so that it only wraps on spaces and not on period or semicolon?